# How to set transaction isolation level none in mysql?

Tags: mysql, isolation-level, isolation, transaction-isolation

I want to test the transaction isolation issues : lost update. How can I do that in mysql console. I know the following one

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

Using read uncommitted i can demo it does not allows lost update but allows dirty read. I want to demo the lost update how do I demo that practically in two different mysql consoles.